# If $\Lambda$ is an injective bounded linear functional, does it attain its norm on the Closed ball.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $\Lambda$ is an injective bounded linear functional (from a Banach space), does it attain its norm on the Closed ball? I have run into a problem that seems imply this statement. Is this true?

Comment: Do you mean linear *operator*? A linear *functional* is a mapping from a vector space to its field of scalars, so it can only be *injective* if the space is one-dimensional. That the statement holds for *one*-dimensional Banach spaces is (almost) trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant 'bounded linear function' when you said 'bounded linear functional' then the answer is NO: Let $X$ be $\{f \in C[0,1]: f(0)=0\}$ and define  $T: X \to C[0,1]$ by $Tf=\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$. Then $T$ is an injective bounded linear function with norm $1$. If $\|f\|=1$ and $\|Tf\|=1$ then $1=|\int_0^{x_0} f(t)dt | \leq \int_0^{x_0} 1 dt\leq1 $ for some $x_0$. But then $f\equiv 1$ on $[0,x_0]$ which is a contradiction.